# Searching strings and metadata in multiple files

Tags: python

Need to search thousands of files for specific strings/metadata, hex tags etc but this python code Ive done only searches the one file which would take an extremely long time

```
def check():
        datafile = file('example.txt')
        found = False
        for line in datafile:
            if blabla in line:
                found = True
                break

        return found

found = check()
if found:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the file name/path a parameter to the function.  Then your function can process any file, not just one particular file.  Then, call the function for each file that you want it to process.  You will probably want to make a list of the file names/paths to process, then have a loop that does what you want for each file.

Eg.

```
def check(fname):
    datafile = open(fname)
    found = False
    # ...
    return found

files = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for fname in files:
    found = check(fname)
    if found:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are all contained in a directory "/foo":

```
import os, re
#Use a re.findall() to avoid line-by-line parsing
myrex = re.compile('blabla')

def check(filename):
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        matches = myrex.findall(myfile.read())
        return len(matches) > 0

os.chdir("/foo")
#Use an os.walk() to find the names of all files in this directory
for root,dir,files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in files:
        print fname + ": " + str(check(fname))
```

If the files are stored in multiple locations, you'll need an extra loop around the "os.chdir()" block.
If you have multiple patterns you're searching for, use another "re.compile()".

Does this help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider `glob` or `os.walk` to retrieve filenames, but something like:

```
import fileinput

print any(blabla in line for line in fileinput.input(['some', 'list', 'of', 'file', 'names'])
```

This automatically reads the files sequentially and will short circuit on the truth test.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in a single directory you can get them with `os.listdir()`. This will give you a **list** of all the files in the directory. From there, you can access each one with, for example `os.listdir('/home/me/myData')`. If you are on a unix based system: `grep` is a very powerful tool that will give you much flexibility. You may want `grep -r "your query" ./ > results.txt`. This will give you every line that matches your search and includes the option of using regular expressions... and saves it to a file. Otherwise, to search a lot of files with python only:

```
def check(x):
    return "blabla" in x
files = os.listdir('/home/me/files')
for f in files:
    x = open(f, "r").read()
    print check(x)
```

*My check function behaves differently as it doesn't check line by line and `True` and `False` are printed with capital letters.*

I imagine you might want to know which file the results came from. (and what line?)

```
for f in files:
    x = open(f, "r").read().split('\n')
    for count in range( len(x) ):
        if check(x[count]):
            print f + " " + count + " " +x[count]
```

...or whatever you need to know.